# regex "label: value,label:value,..."

Tags: regex, scala

I have a string that looks like a comma separate list of "label:value" items.

```
package testParsers

import org.scalatest.{Matchers, FlatSpec}

class testReturnStrParser extends FlatSpec with Matchers{
  import parsers.ReturnStringParser

  "return string parser" should "find the height in ret string" in {
    val teststr = "blahblah:123, height:80.3"
    val s = ReturnStringParser.findVal("height", teststr)
    s should have length 1
    s.head shouldEqual ("80.3")
  }

  it should "work if it is in the middle" in {
    val teststr = "blahblah:123, height:80.3,weight:100.0"
    val s = ReturnStringParser.findVal("height", teststr)
    s should have length 1
    s.head shouldEqual ("80.3")
  }

}
```

I am trying to make the class work when the label `height` is in the middle:

```
package parsers

object ReturnStringParser {
  def findVal(fieldName: String, s: String) = {
    val rx = s"(?<=$fieldName:)"+"(.*)*[^,\\s]*"
    (rx.r)
      .findAllIn(s)
      .toList
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
val rx = s"(?<=$fieldName:)"+"([^,]*)"
```

https://regex101.com/r/aC4vA3/1